# Is there any better solution to avoid my "memory exceeded" error in hackerearth problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from math import gcd
n,k=input().split()
n,k=int(n),int(k)
def phi(a): return sum([gcd(a, b)==1 for b in range(1, a+1)])
if n>=1:
    while k!=0:
        n=phi(n)
        k-=1
print(n)
```

My question is how can i calculate phi number to "k" times in shorter way. My code is up there, when i try to submit this code 9 of test accepting but other one's not because the memory exceeded. How can i fix this problem?

I tried loops but time limit exceeded. Now i'm trying functions from math library.

Edit:
I find 2 new code better then my ex code. Here they are but they accepting 30 of 45 tests because run time or time limit exceed or memory limit exceed. It have the accept all for solved result.

Code 1:

```
from math import gcd
import math
n,k=input().split()
n,k=int(n),int(k)
MAX = 10**5

def sieve_for_primes_to(a): 
    size = a//2
    sieve = [1]*size
    limit = int(a**0.5)
    for i in range(1,limit):
        if sieve[i]:
            val = 2*i+1
            tmp = ((size-1) - i)//val 
            sieve[i+val::val] = [0]*tmp
    return [2] + [i*2+1 for i, v in enumerate(sieve) if v and i>0]

PRIMES = sieve_for_primes_to(MAX)


def phi(a):
    original_n = a
    prime_factors = []
    prime_index = 0
    while a > 1: # As long as there are more factors to be found
        p = PRIMES[prime_index]
        if (a % p == 0): # is this prime a factor?
            prime_factors.append(p)
            while math.ceil(a / p) == math.floor(a / p): # as long as we can devide our current number by this factor and it gives back a integer remove it
                a = a // p

        prime_index += 1

    for v in prime_factors: # Now we have the prime factors, we do the same calculation as wikipedia
        original_n *= 1 - (1/v)

    return int(original_n)
if n>=1:
    while k!=0:
        n=phi(n)
        k-=1
print(n)
```

Code 2 (this one is better the other one for the test results):

```
from math import gcd
import math
n,k=input().split()
n,k=int(n),int(k)

def phi(a):
    
    result = a;

    p = 2;
    while(p * p <= a):
        
        if (a % p == 0):
            
            while (a % p == 0):
                a = int(a / p);
            result -= int(result / p);
        p += 1;

    if (a > 1):
        result -= int(result / a);
    return result;

if n>=1:
    while k!=0:
        n=phi(n)
        k-=1
print(n)
```

Edit 2;
For you guys see the all problem i'm sharing problem screenshot below this edit.
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhQu2.png)

Edit 3;

Some time limit exceeded input screenshots;
[INPUT11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72SAG.png)

[INPUT27](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUFDJ.png)

[INPUT29](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdNfu.png)

Comment: The trick might be *avoiding* computing `phi` k times.

Comment: What's the task, and how large can n and k be?

Comment: @ScottHunter It's not accumulating anything across all the calls to `phi()`, so I don't see how that would cause a memory exceeded problem. Each iteration should release the memory from the previous one.

Comment: What do you mean with "shorter way"?

Comment: It's large so much, hackerearth doing this test not me. So it can be millions n and k. @KellyBundy

Comment: IDK too @Barmar. I just need to fix this. Unfortunaly i have to compute phi k times because solve to hackerearth problem solve.

Comment: I mean its need to work before time limit and memory limit exceed. @KellyBundy

Comment: Wait now we have more than one question. Which code is your question about? Can you limit your question to one, specific issue?

Comment: You can prefer my last code. All of them for one purpose and my question how can i reach this purpose @trincot

Comment: Does this not come down to "please solve this hackerearth challenge for me"?

Comment: No, i'm trying to solve the problem like 2 days also i'm giving code to you for fix the my code, not for write all of it. I'm just a university first class student, i think i tried my best. You don't have to help me, anyone who want to help can be helpful. @trincot

Comment: Can you edit your question and include (1) the challenge description, including examples, constraints for the input, ..etc (2) link to where this challenge can be taken (3) add the input for which you have an error.

Comment: https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/phi-phi-phi/?source=list_view this is the challenge link(2). I got time limit exceed error for all my codes(3). Unfortunaly i can't share the challenge description or some thing like that, you can check the link for all of them(1).

Comment: A question should be self-contained. What is the input for which you have the error?

Comment: I got error 10-15 of 45 tests. And like i said because the TLE (time limit exceed). For example n=847288609443 k=1000000000000000000, n=320000000218295039 k=4, n=640464442610769193 k=40.

Comment: *"i can't share the challenge description or some thing like that"* - Sure you can. Why not?

Comment: Because there is some math sembols in the description so i can't copy that but i will add a screenshot to my question, so you can check easly.

Comment: You said "millions". To those numbers aren't "millions".

Comment: Yes, i said millions. That screenshot just a example. I'm adding the Time limit exceeded some inputs too for persuade to you guys.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use a list comprehension. That requires allocating memory for all the GCD results. `sum()` takes any iterable, so it can sum a generator, which doesn't need to save all the results at once.

Also, the GCD of two numbers is 1 whenever neither is a multiple of the other. So you can replace the call to GCD with two modulus tests.

```
def phi(a): 
    return sum(a % b != 0 and b % a != 0 for b in range(1, a+1))
```

Comment: Unfortunaly it didn't worked, it said wrong answer from all tests.

Comment: Does it work if you go back to calling `gcd()`? Maybe I'm confused about the math.

Comment: It's works for 9 test of 45. Other one's getting time limit or memory limit exceed.

Comment: Do you have your own GCD function? You may need to optimize that as well, to prevent the TLE.

Comment: No i don't have. I edited my question, you should need to look.